# Trivia with exact answer field (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set up questions with a text field for answers. Only after the exact answer has been entered can the next question be shown. I'm getting an error code with "if answerField == answers[currentQuestionIndex]" I believe I need to have allowances for what can be entered as answers. I'm stuck and could use some help in the right direction. thank you

```
@IBAction func answerField(sender: AnyObject) {
    for index in 1...5 {

        if answerField == answers[currentQuestionIndex] {
            ++self.currentQuestionIndex
            if self.currentQuestionIndex == self.questions.count {
                self.currentQuestionIndex = 0
            }
        }

    }
}


let questions: [String] = ["From what is cognac made?", "What is 7+7?", "What is the capital of Vermont?"]
let answers: [String] = ["Grapes", "14", "Montpelier"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    currentQuestion.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]

}
```

Comment: What is calling `answerField` and what is `answerField` - why are you making life hard by having 2 apparently different things with the same name?

Comment: Error code: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '(AnyObject)->()' and 'String'

Comment: I was attempting to use answerField as the trigger for the next question. Once answerField==answer then it would signal the next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`answerField` as you've shown it here is not a `UITextField`; it is a function. That is what the error is telling you: A function that takes `AnyObject` as a parameter and returns nothing (`(AnyObject)->()`) can't be compared to a `String`.

I think perhaps what you wanted to do was create an outlet (not an action) for your answer field:

```
@IBOutlet weak var answerField: UITextField! // Make sure you actually hook this up to your text field in the storyboard.
```

Then, listen for changes to the content of the text field:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    answerField.addTarget(
        self, 
        action: #selector(answerChanged(_:)), 
        forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

    currentQuestion.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
}
```

And then handle changes to your answer field text:

```
func answerChanged(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if (answerField.text ?? "") == answers[currentQuestionIndex]
    {
        currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex + 1 < questions.count ? currentQuestionIndex + 1 : 0
        currentQuestion.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    }
}
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'm understanding where I was wrong. I'm still having issues with answerField.addTarget(
        self, 
        action: #selector(answerChanged(_:)), 
        forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)  Error code: Expected separator. I understand I need to have the text field be a variable for the user to enter, then compare it to the answer, then triggering the next question if correct

Comment: Sounds like you have a typo somewhere. Remove the `answerField.addTarget` call. Do all errors go away? If not, fix the errors before adding the call back in. If all errors are gone, type the command in, using code-completion to help you get it right.

Comment: Using code-completion, the problem is with "action: (answerChanged(_:)) Error Code: Expected expression in list of expressions

Comment: Try `action: "answerChanged:"`, with "answerChanged:" in quotes and with a colon at the end inside the quotes. You might be using an older version of Xcode. Even if you aren't, Xcode should give you a warning and help fix the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you answerField variable is UIText field then you need to use its text. The is an optional property so you also need to unwrap it

```
if (answerField.text ?? "") == answers[currentQuestionIndex]
```

From error code mentioned seems like you don't have variable answerField and you are trying to compare function itself to String, that doesn't make any sense

Comment: I unwrap it and it now has and error code: 
"Value of type '(AnyObject) -> ()' has no member 'text', is that because until the user enters a value it has no text?

Comment: The problem is that answerField is not a UITextField. You need to link you text field with some variable.